# How to add optional claims to B2C access tokens

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, access-token

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims it should be possible to add optional claims to a JWT access token or ID token issued by Azure AD, and **email** is a predefined optional claim. We have added these lines to the manifest for the API application (and to the client application, just in case we were misunderstanding):

```
    "optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "email",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
```

The issuing of ID tokens and access tokens continues to work as before. But access tokens on behalf of an authenticated user whose profile does have an email still do not include the **email** claim. We originally set **essential** to **false**, but that value has made no difference. The **email** claim is included, and always has been, in the ID token returned to the client by our custom policy.

We are working in an Azure B2C tenant, not AAD, and I wonder if optional claims are not supported in B2C access tokens. Is that the case, or is there something else we just aren't understanding about this documentation?

Comment: Try AAD B2C docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: It was worth double checking, but all of our user flows already include email. As I said, the ID token does include the email claim; it's only the access token that doesn't.

Comment: AAD optional claims have not been designed for B2C, if anything works, it wasn’t even intended.